# getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an error with the code below but can't figure out what's wrong.. any advise would be much appreciated!

```html
<div id="thumbnails">
         <img src="img/image_1.jpg" id="img1" onmousedown="bigImage(this)" onmouseover="hoverFuc(this)" />
</div>
```

```js
function bigImage(gallery){
  var imgLG = document.getElementsByTagName("img").getAttribute("src");
  console.log(imgLG);
```

Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).getAttribute is not a function

Comment: getElementsByTagName — pay attention to the 's'

Comment: E.g. `getElementsByTagName("img")[0]`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no attempt at debugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgLG = document.getElementsByTagName("img").getAttribute("src");
```

This statement is not valid, because `document.getElementsByTagName("img")` will return an array. So you should do it like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src");
```

Comment: It **does not** return an Array. It returns a NodeList, which is significantly different.

Comment: @jhpratt, It does not return a NodeList, it return a HTMLCollection.. :D